# Commenting out a var declaration that references an array changes behavior. Why?

Tags: javascript

I have the following java script snippet

```
    <script>
    var editables = document.getElementsByClassName("canEdit");
    function editHandler(el) {
        return function() {
            window.alert(el.textContent);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < editables.length; i++) { 
        var el = editables[i];
        el.onclick = editHandler(editables[i]);
    }
    </script>
```

If I comment out the line `var el = editables[i];` then the alert no longer pops up when I click on an editable element. Why is this the case?

Comment: Because the very next line uses `el` that is not there anymore

Comment: Probably because `el.onclick = editHandler(editables[i]);` is a runtime error if `el` is not defined.

Comment: Oops, yes, very stupid mistake I made. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That line defines `el`. Without it there is no element to attach an `onclick` handler to. If you are not getting a reference error there, there must be some (likely global, if your code snippet is accurate) variable called `el` already defined somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Uh? I would say that line defines `el` which is used to bind the event handler.

Comment: Thanks, I just got burned by scoping and thought I must have been missing something, but it turns out I just made a stupid mistake and don't know how to debug.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is this the case?

Because you used `el` to bind the event handler. If you comment out the line

```
var el = editables[i];
```

then the variable `el` won't exist and

```
el.onclick = editHandler(editables[i]);
```

will throw a reference error because you are trying to access the `.onclick` property of a non-existing variable. *The event handlers are never bound.*

You could use `editables[i]` instead:

```
editables[i].onclick = editHandler(editables[i]);
```

Comment: Or use the micro optimisation for both :)